# Помогите определить вводную конструкцию

Tags: пунктуация

"Все были счастливы в этот, по-осеннему теплый, солнечный день".

Можно ли считать "по-осеннему теплый" вставной конструкцией? Или после слова "теплый" запятая не нужна? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Лучше вообще без запятых. Первая точно ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Все были счастливы в **этот по-осеннему теплый, солнечный** день.*

**Пояснение**

1. Определения "***по-осеннему теплый***" и  "***солнечный***" сближены по значению (общее приятное впечатление от тепла и света), поэтому это однородные определения, между ними ставится запятая.
2. Можно ли обособить определение ***"по-осеннему теплый"***? Указательное местоимение  "этот"  относится к обоим однородным определениям, поэтому обособить "*по-осеннему теплый*" нельзя.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (по комментариям)

Следует особо подчеркнуть, что обособление определения после указательного местоимения "этот" невозможно **для трех определений**, потому что местоимение "этот" должно относиться к обоим определениям.

Но обособление в принципе возможно при наличии только **двух определений**: *Все были счастливы **в этот, по-осеннему теплый,** день*.

Сравнить у Розенталя (п. 4): *Хотелось отличиться перед **этим, дорогим для меня**, человеком* (М. Г.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Answer (score 0):

Если есть однородные определения, одно из которых является указательным местоимением, как ‟это”, то между ними не ставится запятая. Запятая может ставится только тогда, когда однородное определение относится к указательному местоимению как пояснение или уточнение, но здесь не тот случай. Пример из Розенталя:

> Эти недавно опубликованные стихи были написаны много времени назад (Газ.);

[Ссылка на Розенталя, пункт номер 4.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)

Правильная пунктуация: **Все были счастливы в этот по-осеннему теплый, солнечный день.**

Comment: А можно написать: Все были счастливы в этот, по-осеннему теплый, день. Сравнить: Хотелось отличиться перед этим, дорогим для меня, человеком . Я это к тому говорю, что у нас ТРИ определения, поэтому обособить нельзя. А если ДВА определения, то в принципе можно.

Comment: Нет, потому что ‟по-осеннему тёплый” не может иметь статус пояснения. Пояснение это когда мы делаем некое отступление, которое, как понимаем по ходу произношения, необходимо слушающему для понимания смысла.

Comment: Почему не может? Дополнительна информация, уточнение, да что угодно.

Comment: Тёплый, приятный, солнечный это ряд определений, создающих общее впечатление. Одно из таких определений не может быть пояснением.

Comment: Я говорю про два определения: в этот, по-осеннему теплый, день.

Comment: Для того чтобы быть счастливым, мало того, что день по-осеннему тёплый. Так что нет.

Comment: А что еще нужно для счастья? Чтобы солнечным был?

Comment: По-осеннему тёплый, то есть не совсем тёплый.

Comment: Осень, холодно, а тут вдруг стало тепло.  Сразу настроение хорошее.